# How to link fast api and angular form

Tags: angular, api, multipartform-data, fastapi, form-data

I'm new to fast api I really know nothing about it, and now I want to do a small application using it.

I have a form created with Angular and I want to show me a text below the form when all the information are completed. The problem now is I don't know how to link it with fast api so that i can send the data to web server then show a message below my form.

The purpose is understanding how does fast api work with angular especially.

Please can someone suggest a tutorial that explain that .. I searched but didn't find what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is nothing special about FastAPI in that regard; you want to look at making Angular communicate with a backend service through HTTP requests: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Y like MatsLidnh mention above. There is nothing special about FastApi.

You need to create service to handle http request. And use it whenever you wants.

Example of service for HttpRequest.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {


  private REST_API_SERVER = "http://localhost:8000/"; //url of your BE
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getTypeRequest(url) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER+url).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }

  postTypeRequest(url, payload) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.REST_API_SERVER+url, payload).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }

  putTypeRequest(url, payload) {
    return this.httpClient.put(this.REST_API_SERVER+url, payload).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }))
  }  
}
```